# Ros2 humble unable to locate ros-humble* (Debian bookworm)

Tags: ros, ros2, ros-humble, debian

I am on Debian bookworm and can't locate the packages ros-humble-desktop and other ros-humble*.

This post is 1 to 1 the same, as [another one](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/103537/unable-to-locate-package-ros-humble-desktop-ubuntu-22-04), but the difference is that I'm on amd64 (and debian), and the answer on that one is not an answer for my case.

On debian, without any additional commands, I already can locate some files, such as ros-core, ros-desktop etc., but it doesn't work (roscore can't start, because rosversion returns "uknown").
Then I've proceeded according to [documentation for installing Debian packages on Ubuntu](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html).

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common

sudo apt update && sudo apt install curl -y
sudo curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.key -o /usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg

echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list > /dev/null
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

none of the commands returned any errors. As far as I understand, update and upgrade returned no errors, so the packages for bookworm should have been found. Yet I only can locate the same packages, as beforehand, without any changes (update and upgrade also didn't change anything)

```
$sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu bookworm InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Comment: It may stray from the core issue, but in ROS Humble, which is ROS 2, it doesnt execute roscore.

Answer (score 0):

Debian Bookworm is not a platform with debian packages available for ROS Humble. You can see more in [REP 2000](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#humble-hawksbill-may-2022-may-2027).

The bootstrap utilities are provided such that you can compile ROS from source, though Bookworm is much newer than Humble so if you want to use bookworm directly you should be using [Jazzy or Rolling](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#jazzy-jalisco-may-2024-may-2029)

The other ROS packages without a rosdistro name in them are from upstream. Please make sure not to mix them: https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/The-ROS2-Project/Contributing/Developer-Guide.html#upstream-packages

Answer (score 0):

Or... (at your own risk) instead of this

```
echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list > /dev/null
```

do this

```
echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ros-archive-keyring.gpg] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2.list > /dev/null
```

In your system `$(lsb_release -cs)` translates to `bookworn` which is not supported in ROS. Just hardcode `jammy`. But be ready for your system to self destruct :P

I would follow Tully's advice though